# Ubuntu, failed to join an AD over TLS/SSL with realmd

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, ldap, active-directory, sssd

actualy I tried to establish a connection between a Ubuntu-Host and an Active Directory, with the goal to authentification my Linux-Host over the AD.

For this, I use SSSD and Realmd, but not ADSys. We want to work Distribution independent.

So I have two commands for you. This is the command thats work:

```
sudo realm join domain.de --user linuxad --computer-name linux006 --computer-ou "OU=Linux,OU=domain,DC=de"
```

...and this is the command, how sould works:

```
sudo realm join domain.de --user linuxad --computer-name linux006 --computer-ou "OU=Linux,OU=domain,DC=de" --use-ldaps
```

The different is the last flag.

So, an authentification is working, but just in the normal variation. We want the secure, the variation with a S an the end, over TLS/SSL. The problem is, the host cant initialize a connection, see the message below.

```
Jan 15 14:36:58 linux006 realmd[586140]:  * Resolving: _ldap._tcp.domain.de
Jan 15 14:36:58 linux006 realmd[586140]:  * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 1.2.3.4
Jan 15 14:36:58 linux006 realmd[586140]:  * Successfully discovered: domain.de
Jan 15 14:37:04 linux006 realmd[586140]:  * Unconditionally checking packages
Jan 15 14:37:04 linux006 realmd[586140]:  * Resolving required packages
Jan 15 14:37:04 linux006 realmd[586140]:  * Joining using a manual netbios name: linux006
Jan 15 14:37:04 linux006 realmd[586140]:  * LANG=C /usr/sbin/adcli join --verbose --domain domain.de --domain-realm DOMAIN.DE --use-ldaps --domain-controller 1.2.3.4 --computer-name linux006 --computer-ou OU=Linux,OU=domain,DC=de --login-type user --login-user linuxad --stdin-password
Jan 15 14:37:04 linux006 realmd[586140]:  * Using domain name: domain.de
Jan 15 14:37:04 linux006 realmd[586140]:  * Using computer account name: linux006
Jan 15 14:37:04 linux006 realmd[586140]:  * Using domain realm: domain.de
Jan 15 14:37:04 linux006 realmd[586140]:  * Sending NetLogon ping to domain controller: 1.2.3.4
Jan 15 14:37:05 linux006 realmd[586140]:  * Received NetLogon info from: LINUX006.domain.de
Jan 15 14:37:05 linux006 realmd[586140]:  * Using LDAPS to connect to 1.2.3.4
Jan 15 14:37:05 linux006 realmd[586140]:  ! Couldn't initialize TLS [Connect error]: (unknown error code)
Jan 15 14:37:05 linux006 realmd[586140]: adcli: couldn't connect to domain.de domain: Couldn't initialize TLS [Connect error]: (unknown error code)
Jan 15 14:37:05 linux006 realmd[586140]:  ! Failed to join the domain
```

I know, thats I need a puplic-cert from the active directory - so someone who does know more as me have me created a base64 certification on the AD (CA), what I putted under /etc/ssl/certs. I also updated the certs on the host with sudo update-ca-certificates, but as results I getted 0 added, 0 removed; done, what me not giving the feeling of change.

So... Have anyone in this here some experience or an idea establish an connection over SSL?

With best regards,

Alphabeit

Comment: I could solve this problem, by my self. So, I don't know the diffrent between a certification with the ending `.cer` und the ending `.crt`, but after some research I realized, that I needed the secound variation. So, I converted with openssl `sudo openssl x509 -inform PEM -in AD_Cert.cer -out AD_Cert.crt` in the correct form, load them `sudo update-ca-certificates` and its work.